# using eclipse with a remote git respository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I read dozen of tutorials how to do it.
Yet I do not manage to get this to a working state that is usable at all.
I'm coming from SVN where it was just a commit, then it merged automatically. If that was not possible it presented a merge tool.

What I want to do:

- use a remote repository
- the remote repository is my own repository on a server on the local network
- check out the current state to have my local files the same version as the remote
- change those local files in eclipse
- store them back to the remote repository
- another colleague changes files too whilst I did and commits after I did
- now when he stores the files back to the remote it will merge them either automatically where it can just append stuff or it will
  present a merge tool where I have to resolve conflicts
- he resolves the conflicts and can put everything to the remote
- now I can check out and git will tell me that there are updates and so on

I'm pretty sure that this is possible. But with all tutorials I followed I only ended in a state where it would just overwrite the remote or master branches or whatever.

So can we please do the following:

- can someone provide a link to a tutorial how to set all that up in
  eclipse properly with all the actions needed explained (at best for
  egit 3.2.1) that is confirmed working
- then I will use that tutorial as a basis and work myself through it
- if I experience errors I will post the exact problem here

Cause I could tell you that I have an error where it says the original file is gone even thou it is there and when I save the file it warn because it will be overwritten. Or that whatever action (merge, create branch, merge, commit, push, ...) I choose it will always just overwrite stuff on the remote.
But I guess that is of no use if I do not post all my exact steps and that would inlcude to post dozen of screenshots. I'd like to avoid that for obvious reasons.

I lost a whole day with this, which makes me think that git is not really simplifying things. As you might guess I'm in a state of much frustration now. But I understand the concept behind it (I think) and like it. Also I have many problems with svn, so I do not want to go back to that either.

THANKS!

Comment: Learning git can certainly be frustrating; I've been there.  Have you checked out Vogel's tutorial on egit?  It really helped me.  http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html  This should help you get set up with everything you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually the first tutorial I read. Usually vogella is a great sure. But I failed at it this time. Another one was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfeqnernMmE